# Umbraco - Creating variable of nodes - how to check for missing value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, umbraco, xslt-2.0

I am using Umbraco 4.5 (yes, I know I should upgrade to 7 now!)

I have an XSLT transform which builds up a list of products which match user filters.

I am making an XSL:variable which is a collection of products from the CMS database.

Each product has several Yes/No properties (radio buttons). Some of these haven't been populated however.

As a result, the following code breaks occasionally if the dataset includes products which don't have one of the options populated with an answer.

The error I get when it transforms the XSLT is "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32". I assume this is the value being passed into the GetPreValueAsString method.

How do I check to see if ./option1 is empty and if so, use a specific integer, otherwise use ./option1

```
<xsl:variable name="nodes" 
    select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1098)/* 
    [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1' and 
    ($option1= '' or $option1=umbraco.library:GetPreValueAsString(./option1)) and
    ($option2= '' or $option2=umbraco.library:GetPreValueAsString(./option2)) and
    ($option3= '' or $option3=umbraco.library:GetPreValueAsString(./option3)) and
    ($option4= '' or $option4=umbraco.library:GetPreValueAsString(./option4)) 
    ]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Note: you tagged your question as XSLT 2.0, but Umbraco does not use XSLT 2.0, it is (presently) stuck with XSLT 1.0.

> ```
> $option1= '' or $option1=umbraco.library:GetPreValueAsString(./option1)
> ```

There can be multiple causes for your error. A processor is not required to process the or-expression left-to-right or right-to-left, and it is even allowed to always evaluate both expressions, even if the first is true (this is comparable with bit-wise operators (unordered) in other languages, whereas boolean operators (ordered) in those languages typically use early breakout).

Another error can be that your option value in the context node is not empty and is not an integer or empty, in which case your code will always return an error.

You could expand your expression by testing `./optionX`, but then you still have the problem of order of evaluation.

That said, how can you resolve it and prevent the error from arising? In XSLT 1.0, this is a bit clumsy (i.e., you cannot define functions and cannot use sequences), but here's one way to do it:

```
<xsl:variable name="pre-default-option">
    <default>1</default>
    <default>2</default>
    <default>3</default>
    <default>4</default>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="default-option"
    select="exslt:node-set($pre-default-option)" />

<xsl:variable name="pre-selected-option">
    <option><xsl:value-of select="$option1" /></option>
    <option><xsl:value-of select="$option2" /></option>
    <option><xsl:value-of select="$option3" /></option>
    <option><xsl:value-of select="$option4" /></option>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:variable name="selected-option" select="exslt:node-set($pre-selected-option)" />

<xsl:variable name="pre-process-nodes">
    <xsl:variable name="selection">
        <xsl:apply-templates 
            select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1098)/*"
            mode="pre">
            <xsl:with-param name="opt-no" select="1" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- your original code uses 'and', so is only true if all 
         conditions are met, hence there must be four found nodes, 
         otherwise it is false (i.e., this node set will be empty) -->
    <xsl:if test="count($selection) = 4">
         <xsl:copy-of select="$selection" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>

<!-- your original variable, should now contain correct set, no errors -->
<xsl:variable name="nodes" select="exslt:node-set($pre-process-nodes)"/>

<xsl:template match="*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1']" mode="pre">
    <xsl:param name="opt-no" />

    <xsl:variable name="option"
        select="$selected-option[. = string($opt-no)]" />

    <!-- gets the child node 'option1', 'option2' etc -->
    <xsl:variable 
        name="pre-ctx-option" 
        select="*[local-name() = concat('option', $opt-no)]" />

    <xsl:variable name="ctx-option">
        <xsl:choose>

            <!-- empty option param always allowed -->
            <xsl:when test="$option = ''">
                <xsl:value-of select="$option"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- if NaN or 0, this will return false -->
            <xsl:when test="number($pre-ctx-option)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$default-option[$opt-no]"/>
            </xsl:when>

            <!-- valid number (though you could add a range check as well) -->
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="umbraco.library:GetPreValueAsString($pre-ctx-option)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <!-- prevent eternal recursion -->
    <xsl:if test="4 >= $opt-no">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="self::*" mode="pre">
            <xsl:with-param name="opt-no" select="$opt-no + 1" />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
        <!-- the predicate is now ctx-independent and just true/false
             this copies nothing if the conditions are not met -->
        <xsl:copy-of select="self::*[$option = $ctx-option]" />
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="pre" />
```

Note (1): I have written the above code by hand, tested only for syntax errors, I couldn't test it because you didn't provide an input document to test it against. If you find errors, by all means, edit my response so that it becomes correct.

Note (2): the above code generalizes working with the numbered parameters. By generalizing it, the code becomes a bit more complicated, but it becomes easier to maintain and to extend, and less error-prone for copy/paste errors.